# How to install a specific old version of Debian package(libjpeg.so.8) in Jenkins(possibly using snapshot)?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, playwright, apt, debian-based

I'm have been seeing this error while trying to install browser dependencies for Playwright.
16:29:17      browserType.launch:
16:29:17      ╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
16:29:17      ║ Host system is missing dependencies to run browsers. ║
16:29:17      ║ Missing libraries:                                   ║
16:29:17      ║     libjpeg.so.8                                     ║
16:29:17      ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Playwright version: 1.28 (This version of playwright doesn't seem to support the version of OS we have-I'm looking to fix this as a temporary solution for now)

There were other libraries missing, but I managed to fix it by installing them this way:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libicu66 libicu66 libxslt1.1 libopengl0 libwoff1 libharfbuzz-icu0 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libjpeg8 libwebpdemux2 libenchant-2-2 libsecret-1-0 libhyphen0 libffi7 libevdev2 libgudev-1.0-0 libgles2
```

Why doesn't Debian have libjpeg 8? I found the last version of the package located in snapshot: https://snapshot.debian.org/package/libjpeg8/8d1-2/

If someone could point me in the right direction on how to install the package in jenkins, that would be great. Thanks!

Update:

Seeing below error after running the commands provided on Jenkins:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8_2.1.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  
sudo apt install ./libjpeg-turbo8_2.1.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Error:

```
18:25:24  Saving to: ‘libjpeg-turbo8_2.1.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb.3’
18:25:24  
18:25:25       0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 38%  378K 0s
18:25:25      50K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 76%  751K 0s
18:25:25     100K .......... .......... .......... .                    100%  127M=0.2s
18:25:25  
18:25:25  2022-11-26 04:55:25 (659 KB/s) - ‘libjpeg-turbo8_2.1.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb.3’ saved [134436/134436]
18:25:25  
18:25:25  [Pipeline] sh
18:25:25  + sudo apt install ./libjpeg-turbo8_2.1.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
18:25:25  
18:25:25  WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
18:25:25  
18:25:26  Reading package lists...
18:25:26  E: Sub-process Popen returned an error code (2)
18:25:26  E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
18:25:26  E: Problem with MergeList /home/hudson/inmem_workspace/blink-playwright/libjpeg-turbo8_2.1.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
18:25:26  E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 1):

libjpeg.so.8 is provided by the libjpeg-turbo8 package in Ubuntu 22.04. The dependencies of libjpeg-turbo8 are already installed by default in Debian. To install libjpeg-turbo8 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update   
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8_2.1.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  
sudo apt install ./libjpeg-turbo8_2.1.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

There is also a [libjpeg8-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libjpeg8-dev) package (JPEG runtime library) in Ubuntu 22.04 in case you need that package too. Please comment if you need to know how to install other libjpeg8 packages.

Comment: Thank you, @karel. I added these commands to the pipeline, seeing this error during the execution: (updated in the description body)

Comment: This is a generic package management error message, not related to libjpeg8. To solve it read the answers to this canonical question: [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/q/30072/).